# Работа с сетью в iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Собственно, пишу приложение под iOS 4.2.1-устройство. Одна из задач - передавать и получать xml файл на сервер/с сервера. До сих пор с сетями не работал нигде, поэтому возник вопрос - как это  делается? Какие инструменты используют в iOS для этого (насколько я понимаю, web-представления для этого не подходят), или где можно подробно почитать на эту тематику (желательно на русском)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Взаимодействие с сетью можно организовать, используя классы [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)+[NSURLRequest](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=nsurlrequest&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FFoundation%2FClasses%2FNSURLRequest_Class%2F&ei=kT1TT4DzFePe4QTH26HxDQ&usg=AFQjCNFXb75nNwZUBqJek6XK94EWjavM0g).
Однако, большинство XML-парсеров (например, [TBXML](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tbxml&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tbxml.co.uk%2F&ei=nD1TT4mYKaqF4gS9lYzQDQ&usg=AFQjCNEHcFA6X8MNAXjfQRc6EgQCSzxpLQ)) сами умеют скачивать данные, так что напрямую с сетью будете работать только при передаче данных на сервер.

Ссылки:

- [Как отправить POST запрос через NSURLConnection?](http://idev.by/ios/snippets/17309/)
- [Асинхронная загрузка в iOS](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/macosxdev/125510/)
- [Работа с JSON (парсинг) в Objective-C при разработке под iOS](http://arm1.ru/blog/rabota-s-json-parsing-v-objective-c-pri-razrabotke-pod-ios)
- [Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=NSURLConnection&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=NSURLConnection%20пример&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5265edd186c2e4d6&biw=1462&bih=643&pf=p&pdl=500)

Помимо этого, во многих книгах по Objective-C рассматриваются способы работы с сетью:

- [Objective-C 2.0 и программирование для Mac](http://inmac.org/viewtopic.php?t=7950)
- Стивен Кочан - Программирование на Objective-C 2.0
- [Книги для начинающих программистов под iOS](http://theapplegeek.ru/archives/4146)